# Joomla : How to set access permission from a custom component?

Tags: joomla

Currently I am creating a custom component for **Joomla 2.5**.

In this component I need to create users that are assigned to particular user group, say *'Test'*. 
If any user assigned to *'Test'* is loggined from the back-end (i.e. admin login), then I need to hide all admin menus and redirect the user to a particular page inside my component.
In other words that user is restricted from other admin areas.

The problem is that I have to perform all of these actions from my custom component. Is there any way to achieve this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should describe the logic you need to implement in more details. E.g. the part "loggined from back-end" is quite obscure.

Do I understand you correct that you want to deny specific admins to view the admin area and simply redirect 'em to some dedicated page?

Comment: Hi bahrep, thanks for your reply and I will explain my requirements a little more detail. In my custom component i created users assigned to a particular user group, having access to only certain parts of the component. When any of these users loggined by admin login , then i nned to redirect him to a particular page in the same component and he can't access any other parts of the component as well as any other parts of the admin section. i hope now it is more clear to you. (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [Joomla - ACL](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_14) and `download source code` from bottom of the page.